# Facebook PHP-SDK login works ... most of the time?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I have successfully created facebook login on my web-app, **it really works**, but from time to time some user pops up and says that browser gives him "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Because it works in most of the time - respectively it works for most of the users, I wont share the code, because it would not help anything probably. However feel free to ask any more needed info.

Have anyone ever had a similar problem? What might caused this?

Is there a posibility of Facebook returning i different structure data for different users?

While I was searching for a solution I ran up into page when somebody claimed that he solved it by adding something about SSL in the SDK's CURL  connection to facebook.

Some users even claim they have been able to login just fine but the problem started after some time.

But the common scenario is that user clicks login with facebook, gets redirected to the facebook verification/app enabling => is redirected back to my site ( and here *some* users - *not everyone* - gets the browser's redirection loop error ). If everything went fine user is logged in and redirected to his/her profile. If he/she denied the app the error is showed to him/her.

Comment: In chrome network tab press preserve log. You will see all requests then

Comment: This problem never occured to me - to none of my facebook profiles. - so I cant get these error logs :/

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same error "This webpage has a redirect loop". 
Then i tried another code, and it worked perfectly fine.

Here is the link to the code, you can also download entire source code and enter your facebook credentials, it will work.
I have used same code for my website.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-facebook-connect-with-jquery-php

Comment: and was it also happening to SOME users not to all of them, ?

Answer (score 0):

**Third Party Cookies** and **Facebook**

Safari is normally the culprit for this type of error! It is often related to the 3rd party cookie rules in safari. By default Safari does not allow 3rd party cookies to be set (to stop invasive advertising), if you disable this in the settings it should prevent the infinite loop!

When using Facebook controls on your website, it need to be able to set cookies for authentication. These are considered 3rd party cookies (in safari are blocked by default). The facebook dialog you are calling must be request by the user (meaning the user has to have clicked it) in order for the browser to consider this a normal request and not 3rd party.

Safari is not the only browser which has 3rd party cookie settings, so i would suggest trying it in other browsers too! If you can replicate the problem then you can solve it!

This article will show you how to control 3rd party cookies in each browser!

http://feedjit.com/static/howToEnableThirdPartyCookies.html

Comment: Well this problem raised in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox from what I know - do you know how to *disable* third party cookies there? because really just replicating the problem would help me a lot. Anyway, some users have been able to login before...

Comment: Check out the link I added for you! It shows you how to ENABLE third-party cookies in many browsers (inc firefox and chrome). DISABLING third-party cookies is likely to be the problem!

Comment: I want to replicate - I want to disable :)

Comment: let me know how it goes! If that is not the issue then post your facebook login script to your question! :)